# How to Remove Double Quotes in Json Response

Tags: json, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, jsonencoder

My Code Having Json Response Like this

```
["0","0","0","0","0","0","204.4"]
```

Need Like This

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 204.4 ]
```

For this I have done codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query($selectQuery);
    $totalInvoice = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $totalInvoice[] = $row->total;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($totalInvoice));
```

This Response is

```
["0","0","0","0","0","0","204.4"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  **JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)** when encode in json.

**JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)** : Encodes numeric strings as numbers

```
$query = $this->db->query($selectQuery);
    $totalInvoice = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $totalInvoice[] = $row->total;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($totalInvoice, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Awesome Working

Comment: Okay Done @Madhuri Patel

Comment: JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer) Working and Its also Working   (float)$row->total; @Madhuri Patel

Comment: Yes you are right but using `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` you just remove double quotes and number format is same as it shown with quotes but when you use `(float)$row->total; `  then all numbers are converted into float. So its up to what you want exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation @Madhuri Patel